# Race Condition, react-router, flux store update

Tags: reactjs, react-router, race-condition, flux

First some code.

Routes.

```
<Route path="/parent" component={parent}>
  <Route path="/child1" component={child1}/>
  <Route path="/child1" component={child1}/>
</Route>
```

Parent

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {Loading: true}
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.changeListener = ::this._onChange;
    Store.addChangeListener(this.changeListener);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Store.removeChangeListener(this.changeListener);
  }

  _onChange(){
    this.setState( Store.state );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      { 
        this.props.children ?
        React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.state}) :
        null
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The store returns a default opject when first mounted,

```
{
  Loading: true, 
  Child1: null,
  Child2: null
}
```

This Loading field is what is causing the race conditions.

Child1, Child2 look pretty simliar.

```
class Child1/2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    // Action that trigers Store event. 
    Actions.GET_CHILD1_DATA();
  }
  render(){
    // Render logic that depends on teh loading. 
    ....
  }
}
```

Store this is an implementation built on event emitter and Flux

```
class Store extends BaseStore {
  _registerToActions(action) {
    switch(action.actionType) {
      case GET_CHILD1_DATA:
        this.Loading = true;
        this.emitChange();
        // Logic grabbing data from server
        this.Loading = false;
        this.emitChange();
        break;
}}}
```

Feel free to ignore any syntax errors here that is not what is causing the problem i am simply trying to illustrate what is going on.

So the problem arises on the navigation. HEre is the order of events.

1. Child 1 mounts. Loading = true
2. Child 1 triggers actions for API data
3. Store Emits new State based on API call.
4. Parent Updates with new state.
5. Child 1 renders. loading = false

   - Child 1 calls componentWillUnmount() and triggers tore action loading = true // this races, the route and the route wins.
6. Navigate to Child 2 using `<Link />`
7. Child 2 mounts with Loading state from parent, still set to false
8. Child 2 tries to render using data that isn't there.

I load the page on Child1. Child 1 fires Everything works fine. but once i navigate form child1 to child2.

Loading = false; and the child2 assumes that it is done loading and attempts to load a component it has no data for yet.

I have tried to attach a `LOADING_TRUE` action to `componentWillUnmount()` on both of the children. to no avail.

Comment: Move to Redux.. you will not have race condition. i used Flux before it not scalable  and you have to extra work for maintain the race condition